# Как выполнить команду для другой (не текущей) папки с репозиторием?

Tags: git

Пытаюсь выполнить следующую команду, находясь в папке `/var/www/myuser/data`:

```
$ git --git-dir="/var/www/myuser/data/repo-projects/myproject/.git" reset --hard
```

Ожидаю, что в папке `/var/www/myuser/data/repo-projects/myproject/` произойдет откат незакомиченных изменений, но вместо этого файлы из репозитория создаются в текущей папке, в которой я нахожусь.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подсказать *git*-у, что нужно отменить изменения здесь: `/var/www/myuser/data/repo-projects/myproject/`?

Comment: вероятно, ещё work-tree надо указать. файлы в котором вы, собственно, и хотите изменить. всегда стоит помнить: рабочий каталог и хранилище — это две разные сущности. почти не связанные друг с другом.

Answer (score 1):

> но вместо этого файлы из репозитория создаются в текущей папке, в которой я нахожусь

потому что рабочим каталогом по умолчанию является текущий (на самом деле алгоритм поиска рабочего каталога несколько сложнее, но в данном случае это несущественно).

чтобы указать другой каталог в качестве рабочего, можно, к примеру, передать программе *git* опцию `--work-tree=путь`. для приведённого примера (для краткости — с указанием относительных путей):

```
$ cd /var/www/myuser/data
$ git --git-dir=repo-projects/myproject/.git --work-tree=repo-projects/myproject reset --hard
```

а можно было воспользоваться и опцией `-C путь-к-рабочему-каталогу`, с помощью которой задаются оба каталога одновременно: каталогом с хранилищем (то, что задаётся опцией `--gid-dir`) будет каталог `путь-к-рабочему-каталогу/.git`. для приведённого примера:

```
$ cd /var/www/myuser/data
$ git -C repo-projects/myproject reset --hard
```